# Is one RLD electrode enough for multichannel ECG acquisition system?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential, data-acquisition, ecg, electrode

I am trying to design the multichannel ECG measuring device. My device has to acquire 3 signals at the same time. I have to use 6 electrodes to be able to measure those signals. My problem is each channel needs RLD electrode to reduce the CM noise. Since those signals are acquired at the same time using a switch to select the right channel to be used with RLD electrodes is unfeasible. I couldn't find the right way to configure the circuit in order to use one RLD electrode for the different 3 acquisition channels at the same time. Using deferent RLD electrodes for each channel seems to be unrealistic and consumes a great amount of power.

Comment: Please post a schematic of your complete system. Are you using two of-the-shelf devices, each with 2 inputs and 1 RLD and this is the reason you have 6 electrodes? *"each channel needs RLD electrode to reduce the CM noise"* By "channel" you mean electrode?

Comment: Reading this https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/6/6865.html may be helpful. (How to add RLD to a multichannel ECG).

Answer (score 0):

A simplified way of looking at is that you should drive the right leg with the (inverted) average of the other electrodes.

The idea is, you find the “common  mode voltage”, and drive the right leg to reduce that “common” mode to zero. This means if one of your input channels is left unconnected, or is poorly connected, you should not include that channel in your right leg drive calculation.